# Commutator for Solving Coefficients in a Hamiltonian

Tags: equation-solving, function-construction, programming, pattern-matching, functional-style

I am relatively new to Mathematica but I understand the basics.
I want to solve for coefficients by commutator constraints and I have problems implementing the commutator. The setup is the following:

I have two sets of bosonic operators a and b with commutation relations:

```
[a[-i],a[j]]= KroneckerDelta[i, j]
[b[-i],b[j]]= KroneckerDelta[i, j]
```

where i and j take values 1 and 2 and -i is the lowering operator part
and a set of fermionic operator with anticommutation reltaions:

```
{f[-k],f[l]}= KroneckerDelta[k, l]
```

k, l take values from 1 to 4
I have a Hamiltonian consisting of two fields. There are 6 distinct fields overall therefore a general two-fielded Hamiltonian has 36 terms of fields. A field consists of two fermionic operators.
Hence a general term in the Hamiltonian looks like this:
$H \sim k_j \, f_l^{\dagger} f_m^{\dagger} \quad f_p^{\dagger}f_q^{\dagger}.$

The goal is to solve for coefficients $k_j$, which should be possible because I know that the general Hamiltonian should commute with the generators G: $[H, G]=0$. G is a list of generators of the form

$
b_{\alpha} b_{\beta}^{\dagger},\, a_{\alpha}^{\dagger} f_{i},\, b_{\alpha} f_{i}, ...
$

***What I have implemented so far*** is the general Hamiltonian of the form:

```
H = k[1] (f[1] f[2]) ** (f[1] f[2]) + …
```

and a list of generators G.

I defined the commutator with linearity

```
Clear[Commutator]
Commutator[A_ + B_, C_] := Commutator[A, C] + Commutator[B, C]
Commutator[A_, B_ + C_] := Commutator[A, B] + Commutator[A, C]
```

and homogeneity

```
Commutator[k[j_] A_, B_] := k[j] Commutator[A, B] /; 1 <= j <= 36
```

I know that I get the final answer from this line:

```
Table[Solve[Commutator[H, G[[n]]] == 0, k[n]], n, Length[G]]
```

**But how do I implement the commutator to do what I typically do on paper?**

```
Commutator[H, G[[1]]]
```